# Swift 4 Rotation Jumps Back

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm rotating a the minute pointer on my watch icon, but at the end of the animation, it jumps back to the starting position. How can I have it stay where it stopped?

```
let rotation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
rotation.toValue = Double.pi
rotation.duration = 0.5 // or however long you want ...
rotation.isCumulative = true
watchIconMin.layer.add(rotation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UIView animation if watchIconMin is a subclass or class of UIView.

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.watchIconMin.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)
    }) { (success) in
        self.watchIconMin.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)
    }
```